# Ways how to learn Hungarian grammar

Tags: hungarian

Can you recommend any good resourses where I can learn Hungarian grammar elaborately and in details?And are there any dictionaries about the Hungarian language which give not only the meaning of a word and its translation but also its correct usage in the sentence?

Answer (score 2):

Since I'm a native speaker, I probably cannot determine whether a book is good or not. However, I think [it's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/041560009X) quite good and covers the whole grammar of the language in depth.

About the correct usage of words: I don't think there is a dictonary or something like this, but you can use [this](https://www.linguee.hu/). Just type the phrase that you want to use, but be careful, because it may have some mistranslation.